# How to add different labels on a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UICollectionView with custom cells. I now need to add labels to each cell with different text. On this moment I have something static like this;

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
 cell.centerImageView.image = countries[indexPath.row]
 cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 4, y: -10, width: 60, height: 45))
    label.text = "TEXT1"
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10.0)
    label.textColor = UIColor.white

    cell.contentView.insertSubview(label, at: 15)
    
 return cell
}
```

So on this moment, every cell created will have the label 'TEXT1'.
Let's say I have 10 labels, like 'TEXT1, TEXT2, TEXT3' (etc)

I founded some outdated solutions for Swift 3 and can't seem the figure it out for xCode11
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already changing data based upon indexPath.row for image. You just need to do the same for label so you can do the following:

```
// define this outside of the method
let titles = ["TEXT 1", "TEXT 2", "TEXT 3"] // etc

// then inside of your cell for item method 
label.text = titles[indexPath.row]
```

Ideally you would create a class which had the image and the text and then use the class to set the values. Leave a comment if you want this shown.

Comment: Easy as that huh.. :) Thank you!